# parsing timezone %Z strptime() in c

Tags: c, timezone, strptime

Have problem with parsing timezone (%Z) in
strptime(to, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", &tm);

Got the tm.tm_year = 0 because probably %Z doesnt parse timezone well.

The code is:

```
const uint8_t* from = u_name.version;
uint8_t *to = (uint8_t*) malloc(30);
strncpy(to, from+(strlen(u_name.version)-29), 29);

printf("%s\n",to); //"Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 1969"


struct tm tm;
strptime(to, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", &tm);
```

and tm.tm_year is 0;

When I do:
    strptime(to, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S CEST %Y", &tm); 
    everything is okey.

Comment: 1 ) When a function does not perform as expected and that function has a return value code is not checking, the first thing to do is _check the return value_.  What is the return value of `strptime()`?  2) why should `strptime("Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 1969", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", &tm)` be expected to work as it have no timezone in the string?

Comment: 1) return value is null and its cause strptime cant match all format string (probably because of %Z);

2) my mistake, it should be written:
printf("%s\n",to); //"Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 CEST 1969"
up in the code so there is a time zone